# First day of the week and the calendar week

Tags: formula, openoffice-calc

I've to do a bit calc work and need to know how I can get the first day of the current week and the calendar week. It's for my training certificate.

[image: Example sheet]

Comment: Use this formula: `A1-WEEKDAY(A1,1)+1`, where `A1` contains a date in the week in question.  See [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=73340) for more information.

Comment: Cause the function are the same, isnt it ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Don't forget that OpenOffice Calc typically uses a semi-colon to separate parameters within the worksheet functions.

Comment: @Jeeped I assume he will be able to sort out the details given the comment and link.

Comment: I got an Err:508 and in A1 an #NAME? error

Comment: Can you take a screen capture of what you are trying to do.  Include it in your question as an image (or link if you don't have the rights to include an image).  We will look at it and get back to you.

Comment: I just want the first day of the week in one cell. but wait I#ll capture one

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry i miss it every time

Comment: You have a circular reference in cell B6.  Replace `B6` with a cell containing the day of the week.

Comment: I had but It did not work @TimBiegeleisen. Did the cell for exmaple A1 again with `=TODAY()`a formatting ?

Comment: Looks like a German version of openoffice. So the `WEEKDAY` will be `WOCHENTAG` and the `WEEKNUM` will be `KALENDERWOCHE`. Thats why the `#NAME?` error.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thats shit. I hate those translating functionalities... I'll try it

Comment: Got an 511 error @AxelRichter

Comment: Which formula exactly? See https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc_Error_Codes.

Comment: Okey I got it. With which formula I can get the date of the first and last day of the week. Both in different cells. @AxelRichter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Bathsheba, @AxelRichter and more.

The function depends on which language you have set in Open Office. In my OO its german so I'll let my calculation for the first and last day of a work week here:

Monday: `=DATUM(JAHR(HEUTE());MONAT(HEUTE());TAGEIMMONAT(MONAT(12)) - ( TAG(HEUTE()) - WOCHENTAG(HEUTE();2)) )`

Friday: `=DATUM(JAHR(HEUTE());MONAT(HEUTE());TAGEIMMONAT(MONAT(12)) - ( TAG(HEUTE()) - WOCHENTAG(HEUTE();2) - 4) )`

So you just have to translate into your language.
Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 3):

Assume cell A1 contains the formula `=TODAY()`

The calendar week number is `=WEEKNUM(A1)`.

Assuming Sunday is the first day of the week, the first day of the current week can be computed using `=A1-WEEKDAY(A1)+1`

Comment: Should A1 and the other ones formated as something ? I got an #NAME?

Comment: It works for me with no errors in both OpenOffice 4.1.1 and LibreOffice 4.4.4.3.  The result of the calculation formula is a 5-digit number that has to be formatted as a date before it displays correctly.  (Spreadsheets store dates internally as the number of days since day 0: Dec. 31, 1899 - so Jan. 1 1900 is 1, Jan 2 1900 is 2, Jan. 1 2015 is 42005, etc.)

Comment: In LO 5.0.3.2 on Windows I had to use `=WEEKNUM(A1,1)` to make this work.  In AOO 4.1.1 `=WEEKNUM(A1;1)` was required.